# ASP.NET: F5 in Firefox keeps DropDownList value in UI (but not in code)

Tags: asp.net, refresh, postback

I don't really get the meaning of Firefox's behaviour when hitting F5 on a ASP.NET page.

I have a DropDownList (AutoPostBack=true if this is significant) and change the value from "First value" (Index 0, default) to "Second value" (Index 1). The page posts back and filters some lists.

Now, when I hit F5 (or the refresh button in the address bar) the DropDownList keeps my selected value in UI ("Second value"), but when debugging Page_Load() dropDownList.SelectedIndex-Property is 0 instead of 1 which leads to the manner that the DropDownList selection and the lists do not fit. IsPostback is false when hitting F5.

Internet Explorer resets at least the DropDownList which makes it acceptable.
Imho the best behaviour would be to simple do the SAME request again when hitting F5 (with Postback).

I know this is a familiar problem (for me its really a bug in Firefox, isnt it?), but is there some workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Its better to use ctrl + F5 to reload page, it will fully reload page.

Comment: I cannot dictate the customers to always hit CTRL+F5 ;-)

Comment: True, I thought you use F5 while developing. From clients' point of view, I don't think they will use F5. They just use site as per navigation which we have provided.

Comment: You load the Page, then select an item in the DropDown, which fires an AutoPostBack. THEN you immediately hit F5? Firefox (and other browsers) usually then ask if they should resend the information. Do you get that question? What's your answers?

Comment: Nope, I do not get that question. (Maybe because there is an UpdatePanel around?)

Answer (score 0):

No solution but a workaround:

I store the selected value of the DropDownList in a cookie and set it back on every Page_Load.